# Dynamic Jquery Tabs based on Php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I have this php script:

```
          <?php $bets = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `bet` WHERE match_id = '. $_GET['match_id'] ); ?>
                       <?php foreach($bets as $bet): ?> 

                <?php echo $bet->bet_name; ?>

                <?php $choices = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `choice` WHERE bet_id = '. $bet->id );  //fetch choices 
                ?>
                    <?php
                    if(count($choices))
                    {
                        foreach($choices as $choice)
                        {

                            echo "". $choice->choice_name . "";
                                                        }
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<h3> Not found, sorry </h3>";
                    }
                    ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to create a jquery tabs based on these data.

I need a tab foreach $bet that contain the relative $choice.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you need, You need to create both the tabs and their content divs.

Loop through $bets twice, once for the tabs, once for the the panes.

```
    <?php $bets = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `bet` WHERE match_id = '. $_GET['match_id'] ); ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($bets as $bet): ?> 
            <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $count ?>"><?php echo $bet->bet_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php $count++; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
        </ul>                


        <?php $count = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach($bets as $bet): ?> 
            <div id="#tabs-<?php echo $count ?>">
        <?php $choices = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `choice` WHERE bet_id = '. $bet->id );  //fetch choices ?>
        <?php
            if(count($choices))
            {
            foreach($choices as $choice)
            {

                echo "". $choice->choice_name . "";
                                            }
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<h3> Not found, sorry </h3>";
            }
        ?>
       <?php $count++; ?>
        </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?> 

    </div?>
```

P.S. I think a for loop might work better for you than a foreach loop

Comment: Your script works very well ! You had made 2 errors:    </div?> --> </div> and "<div id="#tabs-<?php echo $count ?>">" to <div id="tabs-<?php echo $count ?>">.

Now is ok ;) Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't have a PHP client running so I couldn't test. I was even using notepad as I don't even a php IDE at this time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to download the jQuery library and the UI library if you want to use the jQuery tabs.
There is an example on the jQuery UI tabs page as :

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
 <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
<p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So for each of your bets you can create a "li" tag with the "href" set to the div that will owns the tab content as described in the example.

```
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($bets as $bet): ?> 
    <li><a href="#<?php echo $bet->bet_name;?>"><?php echo $bet->bet_name;?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

And you do the same loop to create the divs...
Once you are done, you need to call the "tabs" function =>

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

Sounds great to me